# How to find the probability of intersection of variables with indicator r.v.

Tags: probability

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of events.

If we let $I_n$ be the indicator r.v. such that $I_n=1$ when $A_n$ occurs and $I_n=0$ if $A_n$ does not occur.

I know that $P(A_n) = E(I_n)$

But why is it that $P(A_j \cap A_k) = E(I_j I_k)$?

Further: If we define $\eta_n = \sum_{k=1}^n I_k$, then

$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_j \cap A_k) = E(\eta_n^n)$

I don't understand this statement either, can someone please help

Comment: $I_j I_k=1$ when $A_j$ and $A_k$ occurs so when $A_j \cap A_k$ occurs, or else $I_j I_k=0$ 

(example: $A_j$ occurs but $A_k$ doesnt so $I_j \cdot I_k=1\cdot 0=0$)


so $E(I_j I_k)=1\cdot P(A_j \cap A_k)+0\cdot P((A_j \cap A_k)^c)=P(A_j \cap A_k)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of the product $I_j I_k$ is
$$I_j I_k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } I_j = 1 \thinspace \land\thinspace I_k = 1 \iff A_j \cap A_k ,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
So $\mathbb{E}(I_j I_k) = 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_j \cap A_k) + 0 = \mathbb{P}(A_j \cap A_k)$.

For the second part:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_j \cap A_k) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{E}(I_j I_k) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1}^n I_j I_k\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n I_j \sum_{k = 1}^n I_k\right) = \mathbb{E}(\eta_n^2).$$

Comment: thanks for such a detailed explanation! is the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n E(I_j I_k) = E( \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n I_j I_k) $ just from properties of expectation? and why does $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n I_j I_k = \sum_{j=1}^n I_j \sum_{k=1}^n I_k$?

Comment: Yes the first statement comes from the linearity of expectation: $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$, and for any $X_1, \dots, X_m$ we have $E(X_1 + \cdots X_m) = E(X_1) + \cdots + E(X_m)$. For the second statement, think about the $\sum_{k = 1}^n I_j I_k$ for a specific $j$. We have $\sum_{k = 1}^n I_j I_k = I_j I_1 + I_j I_2 + \cdots + I_j I_n = I_j (I_1 + \cdots + I_n) = I_j \sum_{k = 1}^n I_k$. Then we sum over all $j$ to get $\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1}^n I_j I_k = \sum_{j = 1}^n I_j \sum_{k = 1}^n I_k$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that:
$$
I_jI_k(\omega) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if }I_j(\omega) = I_k(\omega) = 1 \\
0 & \text{if } I_j(\omega) = 0 \ \text{or} \ I_{k}(\omega) = 0  
\end{cases}
$$
The first case occurs when $\omega \in A_j$ and $\omega \in A_k$, i.e $\omega \in A_j \cap A_k$. The second case occurs when $\omega$ is not in the intersection. Thus rewrite the above as:
$$
I_jI_k(\omega) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if }\omega \in A_j \cap A_k \\
0 & \text{otherwise}  
\end{cases}
$$
making it the indicator of the intersection.